# For each li menu, send attributes by post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

So i have this database:

[image]

And then i have a php script to create a simple menu, with the 'local' column.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM credenciais_sensores where ambiente = '1'";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

<ul class="treeview-menu">
          <?php

                 foreach ($results as $result){
                       $local = $result['local'];
                        $local = substr($local,0,7);
                   echo "<li><a class='post' href='#'>".$local."</a></li>";
                 }

          ?>


          </ul>
```

On the query i select all info, but i only display the 'local'. Now, when i click on one of the items from the menu, i want to somehow send the info of that row by post to another page, without triggering a reload on the page. I know i can do this with GET, but i dont want to show the info on the URL.

I want to send the 'oxi_sensorid' and 'oxi_apikey' by post to another page. Ive tried using jquery post, but i cant get the items to display on the other page...

This is the menu i get printed:

[image]

Now, for example, when i click "Pipo 01" i want to send the Pipo 01 oxi_apikey and oxi_apikey by post with javascript to another file, for example getData.php. Ive tried using ajax to post all data to the getdata.php file but the getdata.php is not receiving them...

Comment: You can do that with `ajax`...can you show us your html result?

Comment: I edited the post to show you what i get, and i explained better what im trying to do. @Hackerman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to modify your *php script*:

```
echo "<li><a class='clsPostData' data-sensorid='".$result['oxi_sensorid']."' data-apikey='".$result['oxi_apikey']."' href='#'>".$local."</a></li>";
```

And your *Jquery* code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.clsPostData').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var objPost = {};
          objPost.api = $(this).data('apikey');
          objPost.sensor = $(this).data('sensorid');
          $.ajax({
             url: 'getData.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: objPost
          }).done(function(responseFromPhp){
             //Do something with the response, like
             alert(responseFromPhp.message);
          });
    });
});
```

Your *getData.php* script:

```
<?php
   $apikey = $_POST["api"];
   $sensorid = $_POST["sensor"];

   $response["message"] = "Grettings from php, we receive your sensorid: ".$sensorid;
   echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Its not working.. Ive tried your solution, checked everything, i always get the popup saying "undefined"